# Navigation issue on workspace site

Tags: current-navigation

I have a work-space site as a sub-site under one of my sites and when I tried to change navigation on the work-space it is showing me the edited links on the navigation but once i go back to work-space home it is showing different navigation . Please check the images 
Image 1 showing how i set up in navigation settings
image 2 showing how left navigation showing after the settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably not your issue, but just in case...  I have (more than once) forgotten to click OK at the bottom of the page after changing navigation settings.

Comment: i did clicked on ok but of no use ..